# Mac battery not charging - Weird behavior

Tags: macbook, battery

I got a new battery a while back. After approximately 10 cycles, it has started exhibiting strange behavior.

After connecting the charger for a minute the charger would show an orange light and then after one minute the green light comes on, and the battery won't charge. After completely draining battery sometimes it starts charging itself again.

Now it is not even charging itself. The charger shows an orange light and then turns to green. The Mac says no battery is connected however I can see the battery connected at startup options..

What is wrong? How can I fix this? Is this a charger issue or a battery issue?

Comment: How long is "quite a while back"? If it's an original Apple part, you should definitely have it checked and possibly replaced under warranty.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, borrow somewhere another charger and try it. If the problem persists it is the battery issue.

I do not know Mac that well, but if this is the case, replacing the battery/charger (depending on what is faulty) seems to be the best option.

Also, there is slight possibility it is not charger/battery issue at all so test thoroughly.